# How to select a tag with a variable value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jquery/javscript.
I have a simple question.

Lets say i have a tag like this:

```
<Table id="mytable" >
<Table>
```

And i want to add some rows to this table.

Then we do like:

```
$("#mytable").append("<tr><td>value</td></tr>");
      //some thing like this may not be having the right syntax
```

Now my question is lets the id of the table is in a variable for example:

```
var table="mytable"; //which is coming from the back end
```

Now my using the "table" variable how can I append the row..?

Is that going to be

```
$("#"+table).append("<tr><td>value</td></tr>");//
```

Can some one help me out in this simple thing?
Thanks,
Swati

Comment: While you did get some useful answers, I'm still going to downvote your question because, really, you didn't do enough background research on your own.  You answered your own question while asking, which means you didn't actually check to see if "does this work?" works.  All of the answers in this case are "yes, you did it right" which isn't actually answering your question.  This just clutters up SO and makes it harder to find *real* questions.

Answer (score 1):

that's correct!

```
var tableId = 'myTable';
$('#' + tableId).append('your row');
```

will append whatever you put in the 'your row' to the table with the id 'myTable'

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you would do it. The selector is only expecting a string, so any form of concatenation or string logic via ternary operators will do the trick. This is a very powerful feature of jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reference an ID like that by storing a variable in advance. This would append table rows/cells. You may need to dig deeper between the rows and cells depending on what you need to do though. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = "myTable";

    $("#" + table).append("<tr><td>row1</td><tr>");
});
```